# Reading a file in a process while a process is writing in c++

Tags: c++

I have a file increasing by time, and need to read the file without any race condition or something in another process in C++ on Windows.

Writing a file is given, and there is no room I can play with it. Only thing I can do is reading it gracefully.

Do you have any idea to handle this case well?

TIA

Comment: C or C++?  Your subject says C, your keyword says C++, your body mentions a, "...process in C++...," which makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

In Win32 you would have to make sure that every writer opens the file with at least read share access, and every reader opens the file with at least write share access.  Further sharing would be required if you have >1 reader or >1 writer.

See here for [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx) docs, `dwShareMode` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You'll almost certainly need to use [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (In both processes) to allow sharing the file at all. If the writing application opens the file in exclusive sharing mode and keeps it open, the reading application won't be able to open the file at all.

From there, preventing race conditions is *fairly* straightforward: each process will typically use [`LockFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365202%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [`LockFileEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365203%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to lock a section of the file for exclusive access while it uses data in that section of the file. In general, you want to keep that period of time as short as possible, so you'll lock the section, read/write, and unlock, all about as quickly as possible (i.e., without doing anything else, if you can avoid it).

Comment: I could not use CreateFile in the writing process since creating and appending a file is done in the app. Can I just use CreateFile and LockFile(Ex) at only the reading process to be guaranteed on no racing condition?

Comment: @user518978: Maybe, depending on how the writing application is written. If it checks the result from attempted writes and reacts accordingly, it might work. If it writes "blindly", just expecting it to work, there's a pretty fair chance you'll see failures (writes that fail, and it doesn't re-try them so the data gets lost).